# How long does it take to train a commercial pilot to fly a fighter jet?

Tags: commercial-aviation, flight-training, fighter, pilots

The question is motivated by the recent events in Ukraine and [the Ukrainian parliament on Monday tweeted that Europe was sending 70 fighter planes to Ukraine](https://www.politico.com/news/2022/02/28/ukrainian-pilots-arrive-in-poland-to-pick-up-donated-fighter-jets-00012560).

If this were to happen, how much time would it take, roughly, to train a commercial pilot to fly a fighter jet? (provided that the pilot is in excellent physical condition)

Comment: The linked and somewhat nebulous article suggests the 70 jets are all models similar or identical to those in Ukrainian service, flown by existing pilots. Suggest edit to define if this question is about this type transition process, which is pretty common and probably has good sources, or the more nebulous 'how long to train an F35 pilot to some arbitrary level'.

Comment: Not an useful answer, but with enough twisting you could claim 12 minutes to learn to fly a fighter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holden%27s_Lightning_flight

Comment: @GremlinWranger The "is this were to happen" meaning that, in the future, Ukraine might need new jet pilots as they could be "running out" of the current ones (could not find a better way to say that, sadly). And since they can't have foreigners. they might have to train pilots from other types of planes, like the commercial pilots.

Comment: There's a fairly high chance that a number of commercial pilots were fast jet pilots _before_ becoming commercial pilots as thats the more usual path to commercial aviation.

Comment: @Jamiec In the US, but in a smaller country like Ukraine? That would be interesting to know...

Comment: @deju vu - the difficulty in answering the question for Ukraine is that it becomes a political one. How acceptable is it for pilots to die, loose aircraft or hit friendly forces due to lack of training?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but, with regards to what prompted it, the types of aircraft that were said to be in the process of being given to Ukraine are ones that Ukrainian pilots have been flying _since the 1970s_. They're _very_ accustomed to these aircraft. Ukraine does have an Air Force. It's not like they would be sending airline pilots to fly them. That being said, it appears that there was some significant miscommunication. The countries that were said to be donating the aircraft have now stated that no such agreement existed, as per updates to the article linked in the question

Comment: Just my guesstimate: Even if such fighters were being donated (how many, in that case, is unclear), I haven't seen information whether they still have radio and other equipment compatible with what the Ukrainian Air Force is using, or whether they have been modernised to NATO standards. If the latter, they would need to be un-modernised to be useful.

Comment: @Déjàvu in regard to the usual carrer path - in post-Soviet countries becoming a civilian pilot without becoming a military pilot first was almost unheard of. On the other hand, not all military pilots are a fighter jet pilots.

Comment: In almost all modern air forces, number of trained pilots typically exceeds number of available aircraft at any point in time.  Historically there have been times where this hasnt held true, such as the Battle of Britain where production exceeded training output, but complexity of aircraft has gone up to the point where maintenance is an issue these days.

Comment: The donated aircraft would be flown in by pilots who can fly them, so maybe you could ask those pilots to stick around for a while and fly them into battle... why the hurry to leave?

Comment: @GremlinWranger Holden took three attempts to land, had a tail strike, broke the parachute, and burned the brakes before stopping 100m from the end of the runway.  I don't think you can call that *"having learned to fly"*  He survived, but it wasn't a success.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

fly it or fight it? There is a major difference.

A few days studying the systems and maybe a few hours in a simulator and/or a two seater with an instructor and he could probably fly the aircraft and take off and land without damaging it seriously enough to need major repairs (depending on the type of course, some are notoriously difficult to handle).

But to operate it effectively as a weapons platform so he's not just flying around in circles while people take potshots at him takes a lot longer. Months, at least in peacetime, if not years.

That's the drawback of how advanced and complex machines have become since 1940 when raw recruits with a few hours of instruction were thrown into the Battle of Britain and expected to defend the realm against the Hun, and succeeded (though at very high cost of life and aircraft).

Comment: I still remember that day some 30+ years ago when as an engineer in the USAF, I was introduced to the reality of a fighter pilot. I was watching a cockpit video from an F-16 while a pilot was narrating how the radar intercept was progressing. The pace was similar to an announcer at the horse races. At some point I asked; When is he flying the plane? The response was; Oh, that's a background task. That's when I realized that an F-16 isn't a plane, it's a weapon system that just happens to fly.

Comment: Everything changes when *"Aviate, Navigate, Communicate"* adds in *"watch for bad guys, identify your mission target, don't get shot, select the correct munitions, configure and target them correctly, evade counterfire, coordinate with air and ground forces, etc, etc, etc..."*.  Just keeping situational awareness is a monumental task by itself.  Consider, for example, how much a bus driver would need to learn before they could effectively command a tank.

Comment: The pilots of SR-71s were *'a little busy'*. Seated behind them, the reconnaissance systems officer did *everything* else.

Comment: @Mazura And the SR-71 isn't even a warplane - no dogfights, no weapons; just cameras, really.  Some multirole/fighter class planes did have a [RIO/WSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weapon_systems_officer), of course.  In an airliner you always have at least two flight crew also and they don't have any extra stuff to worry about at all.  Instead of two pilots managing flight you have one who has to play PF and PM at the same time.  For one-seaters without the luxury of a RIO/WSO you're now down to just one pilot who is PF, PM, and RIO/WSO all at the same time.  The workload is crazy.

Comment: @J...: And yet, pilots of single-seater fighter jets like the F-16 joke about rather having the extra gas than another person in the cockpit with them.  e.g. https://youtu.be/REtqz-zIhP4?t=126 (Mover Ruins Movies: IRON EAGLE (1986)), he says "that's the way it should be" about being all alone in a single-seat cockpit.  He flew F-16s for the US air force reserve, and F-18s for the navy, and now T-38 adversary air for the air force.  If I spent longer looking, I could probably find something less jokey, maybe in one of his interviews on his channel with an F-14 pilot about their RIO.

Comment: (My impression is that older jets with less nice radar / weapons electronics took more attention to get the most out of them, so it made more sense to have a dedicated person managing it.  And also less advanced fly-by-wire meaning that managing the plane itself took more attention?  So single-seat would have been even more of a problem for jets with long-range missiles?)

Comment: This short training looks sufficient for a kamikaze flight.

Comment: @PeterCordes increased automation has reduced the need for a GIB (guy in back), but it's still there for specialised stuff. Hence the EF-18 Growler being a two-seater, and the Strike Eagle, for example.

Comment: What's the reference to "the Hun"? There's no mention of "the Hun" on the WP Battle of Britain page.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- that's a colloquial reference to the attacking Germans.

Comment: @J... While the SR-71 didn't have weapons that doesn't mean it didn't have to worry about incoming weapons.  Various places that didn't like eyes in the sky took potshots at it now and then and the crew had to spoof or outrun the incoming missiles.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Usually outrun.  I believe SOP on the 71 was just to accelerate if fired upon.  It's not like you can do anything aerobatic at FL810 and mach 3.2 without falling out of the sky and missiles don't have the endurance to catch up.

Comment: @J... It's pretty hard to outrun a SAM fired from in front of you.  You're going to have to dodge or jam such a missile.  (Note, however, that most SAMs are pretty easy to dodge at that point--the air is so thin their control surfaces aren't very effective.)

Answer (score 20):

As a baseline answer, the Royal Australian Air Force has a rundown on the recruiting [page](https://www.defencejobs.gov.au/jobs/air-force/fast-jet-pilot), hidden under 'full details' option and 'training' where after completing initial flight training they have:

> Pilot Advanced Courses (1 year). If you are streamed to go down the FJP pathway you will be required to complete the following courses:
> Pilot Advanced Course (6 months). Remaining at RAAF Base Pearce you will undergo training on the Hawk Lead-in fighter at Number 79 Squadron (79SQN).
> Lead-in-Fighter Course (6 months). Once you have learnt the basics of flying the Hawk and operating at higher airspeeds, you will be posted to 76SQN at RAAF Base Williamtown to learn how to operate the Hawk in a tactical environment (air to air and air to ground).

This is training on the Hawk, a fast jet with weapons capability but not a current combat aircraft. Then they have

> Operational Conversions (6 months). At the end of the advanced courses you will be streamed for operational conversion onto one of the following platforms:

And then listing the F18F, F18G and F35

So the starting point for a hypothetical pipeline for pilots to effective fighter pilot is 18 months. While a war footing might let you strip weekends and other down time out it seems unlikely you could do better than 6 months. In practice I would suspect that the key factor in this timelines is training assets - do you have enough simulators, instructors, training aircraft and a safe places to fly for all your pilots, for Ukraine I'm sorta expecting the answer to most of above is 'no'.

So if you need highly effective general purpose pilots you need to have started a year or so ago. If you are at the point of sacrificing one or more of 'effective', 'general purpose' and 'pilot' then other things [become possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamikaze).

Comment: For Ukraine, I'd guess that providing training to potential pilots is something other countries could help with.  i.e. fly the pilot trainees to another country where they can train.  Not that it would make sense, because the timeline for becoming combat-effective is just so long.  Modern jets are too expensive to risk on half-trained pilots, and full training takes a long time.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of January, 2023, Ukraine said that [about six months](https://www.theguardian.com/world/live/2023/jan/29/russia-ukraine-war-kyiv-imposes-fresh-sanctions-on-182-russian-and-belarusian-firms-live?CMP=Share_AndroidApp_Other) are required to train they pilots for combat in western fighter jets such as F-16s.

Ukraine previously [said](https://novayagazeta.eu/articles/2023/01/12/postavka-bolshe-chem-zhizn) they have some pilots who have already completed this training.